# Editing XML Data in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

I need to edit/reorganize various XML documents like XML, XSD, XSL in Eclipse (Luna Service Release 2, 4.4.2).

There are large hierarchies and it's difficult to cut/paste and keep track of where I am. I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin or tool that can track the structure with +/- or tell me where I'm at right now.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: Have you tried the `XML Editors and Tools` that you can install from eclipse.org?

Comment: I checked eclipse.org and was instantly discouraged by hundreds of tools and plugins that CAN'T be installed due to some weird errors like "NullPointerException" or "Invalid registry at site.ru" when I try to install from the Eclipse Marketplace, the level of reliability or quality is quite low.

Comment: Your question is too vague otherwise. If you want to troubleshoot installation, give specifics. What version are you running. From where did you get it. From which Update Site are you installing the `XML Editors and Tools`?

Comment: What package of Eclipse do you have, and what version? For example: **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Mars release**

Comment: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Luna is a version, what about a package or downloaded file name?